# Using update cursor with list of shapefiles?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, cursor, stopiteration

I'm still pretty new to using cursors. What I'd like to do is create a list of shapefiles. Within those shapefiles I would like to populate a field "NAME" with the shapefile name less the .shp extension. I am using 10.1 and my code is below:

```
bufferCalc = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*.shp")
for calc in bufferCalc:
NOTE: This space contains calculations for other fields
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(calc, ("PROJNAME")) as cursor:
    for shp in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
        cursor.updateRow(os.path.splitext(shp))
```

The other calculations I need run smoothly however, the error I get when the cursor is ran states "StopIteration: iteration not started". This has got to be something simple I'm doing wrong but can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Indentation is possibly an issue (`with` should be over further), possibly a paste problem?

Comment: Good point, it is not a paste problem. When I indent further I get the 'Unexpected Indent' error. Is the cursor something I need to remove from the for loop and create a separate process for?

Comment: Why do you have 2 `arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()`?

Comment: I removed the second ListFeatureClasses. Not sure why I had that in there, I believe I had copied the code from elsewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the largest problem was with the structure of the update cursor. Also, you have two `ListFeatureClasses` (you only need one to create the list and start the `for` loop).

Try this:

```
bufferCalc = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*.shp")
for calc in bufferCalc:
    # pull out the shapefile name
    shpName = os.path.splitext(calc)[0]
    # define update cursor
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(calc, ("PROJNAME")) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            # set PROJNAME to the shapefile name for each row
            row[0] = shpName
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Thanks @Erica, that worked perfectly. I'm still learning this stuff and cursors is something I need to get a better grasp of. Thanks again.

Comment: If it worked for you, you can accept the Answer (checkmark under the voting buttons) to the Question gets marked as resolved.